# WebDriver how to select specific LI item

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to figure out how I can set "suborg300" in this LI list?

Thanks for any help...

```
<div id="A3540:pocUserListingTable:0:rpt_sel_fname_panel" class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow">
  <div class="ui-selectonemenu-filter-container">
    <div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="height:auto">
      <ul class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset">
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" data-label="Clear Selection">Clear Selection</li>
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="suborg100">suborg100</li>
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="suborg300">suborg200</li>
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="suborg200">suborg300</li>
        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="suborg400">suborg400</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are the two elements I have tried...the click is successful but the LI item is not selected.

```
str5 = "//input[@id='A3540:pocUserListingTable:0:rpt_sel_fname_filter']";
str5 = "//input[@name='A3540:pocUserListingTable:0:rpt_sel_fname_editableInput']";
if(!driver.findElements(By.xpath(str5)).isEmpty())
{
  clickOK = false;
  try
  {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(str5)).click();
    clickOK = true;
  }
 finally
 {
   if (clickOK)
   {
      System.out.println("click ok");
   }
   else
   {
     System.out.println("click failure");
   }
  }
}
else
{
  System.out.println("element not found");
}
```

Comment: Please post code for what you have tried and what errors, etc you got.

Comment: "//input[@id='A3540:pocUserListingTable:0:rpt_sel_fname_filter']";
    "//input[@name='A3540:pocUserListingTable:0:rpt_sel_fname_editableInput']";
these find the element but the click doesn't select the item.

Comment: Please put it in the question so it can be formatted properly and everyone will be more likely to see it. And please post the actual code, not just the XPaths.

Comment: why is suborg200 and suborg300 intermixed with what the data-label says and what the element-text says? makes no sense, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='A3540:pocUserListingTable:0:rpt_sel_fname_filter']"));

dropdown.click();

WebElement option = popup.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[@data-label='suborg300']"));

option.click();
```

Comment: I don't know why the list has intermixed data labels. Your suggestion failed with element not found :-( I work in QA not Dev.

Comment: It fell thru to the element not found section...the popup never happened so I'm sure it was the element was not visible, right?

Comment: str5 = "//input[@id='A3540:pocUserListingTable:0:rpt_sel_fname_filter']//li[@data-label='suborg300']"; Didn't popup the menu :-( thanks for trying!

Comment: The popup.click thru an error...I will try different strings in your first line ... I think your structure is a good one for this...I just have to find the right popup syntax for it...thanks again...

Comment: Yeah I think so too, you have to find the element, that you need to click, to make the dropdown options appear, then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='A3540:pocUserListingTable:0:rpt_sel_fname_filter']")).click();

List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//ul/li"));
for(WebElement option : list){
    String text = option.getText();
        if(text.equals("suborg300")){
            option.click();
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tan Su but I can't get the first line to pop open the menu so the loop can actually work :-(